# How to update a string's value in every place it is used

Tags: android, string

Like after adding some new data we're doing `adapter.notifyDataSetChanged()` how can we update string's value so that it would be changed in every place it's used

For example:

```
String s;//Declared at beginning
onCreate(){
    textview.setText(s);
}
public void change(){
    s="Hello";
}
```

Now how the value of `s` can be updated inside onCreate()
I've tried to use `s.notify()` but it's showing following error

```
java.lang.IllegalMonitorStateException: object not locked by thread before notify()
```

Comment: `s="Hello"` won't update the textView

Comment: for exception maybe you can try this
synchronized{
    s.notify();
}

Comment: then how to update that @cricket_007

Comment: You need to call actually call `setText`

Answer (score 0):

The better pattern over here is implementing a Setter for `s`.

```
private String s;//Declared at beginning
private void setS(string s) {
    this.s = s;
    textView.setText(s);
}

onCreate(){
    setS("Initial Value") ;
}

public void change(){
    setS("Hello");
}
```